# Index out of range (fatal error) when summing diagonals in square arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I need difference between first and second diagonal in square matrix array

```
func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    var sumFirstDiag = 0
    for i in 0...arr.count-1 {
        sumFirstDiag = sumFirstDiag + Int(arr[i][i])
    }
    var sumSecondDiag = 0
    for y in 0...arr.count-1 {
        sumSecondDiag = sumSecondDiag + Int(arr[y][arr.count - y])
    }
    print(abs(sumFirstDiag - sumSecondDiag))
    return abs(sumFirstDiag - sumSecondDiag)
}

let array = [
    [1,2,3,11],
    [4,5,6,12],
    [7,8,9,90],
    [1,3,5,7]]

diagonalDifference(arr: array)
```

Error message:

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

Comment: So, as `y` goes from 0 to 3, `arr.count - y` will go from 4 to 1. You meant `arr.count - y - 1`.

Comment: As an aside, if the future, let us know what line the error was in. E.g., in this case, which is line 444. We can guess in this case, but sometimes it isn’t obvious.

Comment: A few improvements: 1) `0...arr.count-1` should be just expressed as `arr.indices`. The first form crashes on empty arrays. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md 2) `arr[i][i]` is already an `Int`, there's no need to convert that into an `Int`. 3) ` sumSecondDiag = sumSecondDiag + something` is more simply written as just `sumSecondDiag += something`

Comment: @zizzygirl I take advantage of a lot of different concepts in my answer. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @Alexander I am really happy with your valuable answer, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd share a more functional approach to this same problem:

```
// The sum of elements along the diagonal from top-left to bottom-right
func diagonal1Sum(_ input: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    input.indices
        .map { input[$0][$0] }
        .reduce(0, +) // I wish Swift had a built-in `.sum` :(
}

// The sum of elements along the diagonal from top-right to bottom-left
func diagonal2Sum(_ input: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    zip(input.indices, input.indices.reversed())
        .map { input[$0][$1] }
        .reduce(0, +)
}

// The absolute value of the difference in sums of the two diagonals.
func diagonalDifference(_ input: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    abs(diagonal1Sum(input) - diagonal2Sum(input))
}

let array = [
    [1,2,3,11],
    [4,5,6,12],
    [7,8,9,90],
    [1,3,5,7],
]

print(diagonalDifference(array))
```

There's a few things to notice:

1. `0...arr.count-1` should be just expressed as `arr.indices`. The first form crashes on empty arrays. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

2. `arr[i][i]` is already an `Int`, there's no need to convert that into an `Int`.
3. `sumSecondDiag = sumSecondDiag + something` is more simply written as just `sumSecondDiag += something`
4. Meaningless parameter names like `arr` shouldn't be keyword labels. Compare `diagonalDifference(arr: array)` and `diagonalDifference(array)`. The `arr:` in the first form doesn't really give you any information you didn't already have. You should omit that keyword label using a `_`.
5. You should not print the result out of a function that computes a result like this. Return the result, then print it. This gives users of your function the ability to choose whether they want to print, or not.

And most importantly: you can iterate through `arr.indices.reversed()` to get a sequence of indices that go from high to low, allowing you to access the row elements from top right to bottom left.

This is the key to avoiding the bug you encountered. You forgot the crucial `- 1`, which is why you were accessing the index out of bounds and causing the crash. If you just use the reversed  reverse the array first, then access the `n`th element, you'll get back the `n`-th last value, without needing to remember to do `acc.count - n - 1`.

To pick the row, you still need the regular "forward indices", like `array.indices()`.

You can use `zip(_:_:)` to iterate both of them at the same time, using the "forward index" to select the row, and the "backward index" to select a particular number from that row.

Thanks to [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) for this suggestion.

## Update notes

I revamped my recommendation. I was previously suggesting to use `input[$0].reversed()[$0]` under the misunderstanding that the result of `reversed` would be a view onto the array that would just perform constant-time index arithmetic. [This is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68332664/3141234). Each of these `reversed` calls was doing a full linear reversal of the array.

Comment: I regard the trick with `reversed` as worth the whole price of admission. :)

Comment: What's the price of admission you're worried about? Non-familiarity, or runtime performance?

Comment: Okay, hang on a bit, I'm not so sure now. `arr.reversed()` is a ReverseCollection, but when you call `arr.reversed()[1]` (for instance) you are told that this is a _different_ `reversed` (the Sequence `reversed`) and has actually generated a reversed copy of the array. Thus this is _not_ a specially efficient way to access by reverse index, as I was hoping.

Comment: So it appears that `arr.reversed()` is very efficient as long as you just _loop_ through the resulting collection. But as soon as you try to access by actual index number, you lose the efficiency. So yes it does the math, but not "for free".

Comment: I've been trying to write a benchmark to profile this, but the optimizer keeps outsmarting me and deleting my profiling code lol. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift), I don't see any explicit behaviour when `Base: RandomAccessCollection`. That seems like a real missed optimization :/ I'll throw it at attabench at some point.

Comment: Yet again, `print((0...Int.max).reversed().last)` is near instant even in debug mode (where the code isn't inlined down to just `print(0)`).

Comment: I agree totally about `first` and `last`. It's just indexing by integer that seems problematic.

Comment: `print((0..<Int.max).reversed()[Int.max - 2])` "Terminated due to signal: ABORT TRAP (6)" Hmmmmmmmm

Comment: We weren't sure about that (see the comments above). Matt even opened https://stackoverflow.com/q/68332664/3141234

Comment: yep, that was our conclusion, too.