# Is Swift array reversed()[n] efficient or not?

Tags: arrays, swift

When you call `reversed()` on an array in Swift, you get a ReverseCollection which merely wraps the original array with reversed access. Thus this is extremely efficient:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
for i in arr.reversed() { print(i) }
```

Nothing actually got reversed except the access; the time complexity of `reversed` here is O(1). Cool!

But when I index into `reversed()` by an integer and check Quick Help, it appears I've lost all that efficiency; I'm shown the *Sequence* `reversed()` which generates a new array:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
let i = arr.reversed()[1] // ???? this is a different `reversed()`!
```

And this seems to be true, because a `reversed()` array does not, itself, support indexing by number:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
let rev = arr.reversed()
let i = rev[1] // compile error!
```

So my question is: is it really true that indexing by number into a `reversed()` array, as in my second example, loses the efficiency of the ReverseCollection index reversal?

Comment: This sounds like a question for @Hamish

Comment: @Alexander Oh good, I'm glad you found this, I was going to blip you via the other question. I'm mighty confused at this point.

Comment: Care to post about this on the Swift Forums? If you do, link it here please!

Comment: @Alexander You go ahead; you started it, after all!

Comment: I opened https://forums.swift.org/t/missed-optimization-in-reversedcollection/50427

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, indexing by `Int` is causing you to lose your `O(1)` access into the reversed array. Quite the gotcha!

As you note, `reversed()` here is an overloaded method; on `Array` specifically, you have two definitions to choose from:

1. [`BidirectionalCollection.reversed()`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift#L292), which returns a `ReversedCollection`, and
2. [`Sequence.reversed()`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L709), which turns any sequence into a reversed `[Element]`

The overloading here is most confusing for `Array` itself, because it's the only `Sequence` type such that `type(of: x) == type(of: x.reversed())`.

The Swift type checker prefers more specific overloads over less-specific ones, so in general, the compiler will use the `BidirectionalCollection` overload instead of the `Sequence` one where possible. The rub: `BidirectionalCollection` has an [*opaque* index type](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift#L116), and cannot be indexed using an `Int`; when you *do* index into the collection with an `Int`, the compiler is instead forced to choose the `Sequence` overload over the `BidirectionalCollection` one. This is also why your second code sample fails to compile: Swift code inference does not take into account surrounding context on other lines; on its own, `rev` is preferred to be a `ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>`, so attempting to index into it with an `Int` fails.

You can see this a little more clearly with the following:

```
func collType1<T: Collection>(_: T) {
    print(T.self) // ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>
    print(T.Index.self) // Index
}

func collType2<T: Collection>(_: T) where T.Index == Int {
    print(T.self) // Array<Int>
    print(T.Index.self) // Int
}

let x: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
collType1(x.reversed())
collType2(x.reversed())
```

---

Lest you wonder whether the compiler can optimize around this when the fact of `Int`-based indexing appears to not have any other side effects, at the time of writing, the answer appears to be "no". The [Godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/z8zxc3K6P) is a bit too long to reproduce here, but at the moment, comparing

```
func foo1(_ array: [Int]) {
    if array.reversed()[100] > 42 {
        print("Wow!")
    }
}
```

with

```
func foo2(_ array: [Int]) {
    if array.reversed().dropFirst(100).first! > 42 {
        print("Wow!")
    }
}
```

with optimizations enabled shows `foo2` performing direct array access

```
cmp     qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 24], 43
```

having optimized away the `ReversedCollection` wrapper entirely, while `foo1` goes through significantly more indirection.

Comment: Great digging! Do you know if there are any feasible approaches for optimizing this case? Somehow programming in when Indices are random access and allow for the kind of `i ==> count - i - 1` transformation that would be necessary for O(1) subscripting in this case

Comment: @Alexander Honestly, I'm not sure — optimizing around these overloads requires _significant_ compiler insight into the underlying types, and while `Array` is already special-cased all over the place in the compiler, this seems like a very tricky transformation to perform. You have to be able to reason about all sorts of potential side-effects, which is very difficult (e.g. while making `foo1` behave like `foo2` seems "obvious" in a way, its not at all obvious at the compiler level, with no known mapping between behavior).

Comment: Might be a good question for some of the professional compiler/optimizer engineers via the Swift Forums! I suspect that the full answer is some mix of "the cost-benefit ratio of optimizing this somehow doesn't appear to be worth it" and "changing this sort of behavior is subtle and dangerous" (e.g. how would it behave in the face of further overloads provided by code outside of the stdlib?)

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the compiler side, I thinking if there was a way to express this in userland code, using a conditional conformance of some sort (is there  some protocol that identifies stridable, contiguous indices that would be eligible for this optimization?)

Comment: @Alexander Ah, good question. This should be possible, at the cost of adding another collection type like `ReversedCollection`. You could conceivably add another overload on, say, `RandomAccessCollection`, which returns a reversed collection using the _same_ index type as the underlying collection. But, beyond the `Index` type change, I don't see another benefit to this type — were it not source-breaking to change, you'd get the same benefits by dropping `ReversedCollection`'s custom `Index` type in favor of it's base's index type.

Comment: i.e. it should be possible, but would likely be a bit of a hard sell

Answer (score 2):

Ferber explained the reason very well.

Here's an ad-hoc solution (which may not be preferred by everyone, because we are extending types from the standard library):

```
// RandomAccessCollection ensures fast index creation
extension ReversedCollection where Base: RandomAccessCollection {
  subscript(_ offset: Int) -> Element {
    let index = index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
    return self[index]
  }
}

[1, 2, 3].reversed()[0] // 3
```

Comment: Identical to https://forums.swift.org/t/missed-optimization-in-reversedcollection/50427/5